# How can i translate the file to MTOM type using SOAP-PHP-Curl

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am doing an integration for a certain bank that uses SOAP application.  There is a requirement in one pf the functionalities that the files should be uploaded in MTOM Attachments. This is the xml content of my request.
variables declared are: 
$file = the file that contains .file extension
$fileFormat = is the file format of the file.

```
$soap_request .= "<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:dir=\"http://macquarie.com/mrb/ws/directUpload\">";
$soap_request .= "<soap:Header/>";
$soap_request .= "<soap:Body>";
$soap_request .= "<dir:uploadTransactionFile>";
$soap_request .= "         <uploadReq>";
$soap_request .= "            <uploadFile>cid:".base64_encode($file)."</uploadFile>";
$soap_request .= "            <fileName>".$file."</fileName>";
$soap_request .= "            <transactionType>".strtoupper($fileFormat)."</transactionType>";
$soap_request .= "         </uploadReq>";
$soap_request .= "</dir:uploadTransactionFile>";
$soap_request .= "</soap:Body>";
$soap_request .= "</soap:Envelope>";
```

I am getting a response that "File is not a valid payment file". Am i doing the right way to MTOM the attachments? If not, can anybody lead me that to do? Thanks in advance